# Оформить JS в отдельный модуль

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

как вот этот код можно оформить в отдельный модуль (NextJS) чтобы потом на каждой странице подключать через import?

```
const checkAuth = async (values) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/refresh`, {
            withCredentials: true,
        });
        setIsAuth(true);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.response?.data?.message);
    }
};
if (localStorage.getItem('token')) checkAuth();
```

Comment: `export const checkAuth ....` или в самом низу файла допишите `export { checkAuth }`

Comment: да нее, так пробовал, не работает че-то

Comment: Сделайте `import {checkAuth} from <your_module>; console.log(checkAuth)`. Посмотрите что выдааст